# Pin 13 - Frozen

Tags: discussion

Our beloved chatroom: "Pin 13" is frozen (due to inactivity).

**Can we re-open the chatroom?**

Theoretically, we could start a new chatroom, but that wouldn't be a very neat solution (it can be hard to find anything back, if we keep making new "Pin 13"'s.

**Can we avoid getting it frozen?**

How to avoid getting the same problem in the future? Can a room be pinned, or made as default general chat of a certain SE? Or do we have to program an Arduino to post random links to it every now and then? ;D

**Should we even?**

The room is frozen, since it was inactive. Theoretically, this means that the room seems to have little function.

Though I believe that it can be usefull to have a general chat.

Comment: How can it be *beloved* and *inactive* **at the same time**?

Comment: @Dat Ha, I believe it had sparked a lot of interesting discussions. But it may be inactive from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've unfrozen it.

> How can it be beloved and inactive at the same time?

Dat Ha has a good point. It has gone recently for 32 days without activity.

If it goes for 14 days without activity it is frozen automatically. I suggest you chat away in it from time to time to stop that happening.

Comment: I think it has potential, and has proven to be usefull. Currently, it just doesn't really keep momentum. My question was also: 'should we even', if anyone has an interesting topic, he/she could create a room specific for that topic. But it feels a little odd to not have a general chat.

Comment: It seems the Arduino users aren't all that chatty. I think a lot of other parts of Stack Exchange have quite active chat.

Comment: There's a lot of foreigners and one-time visitors, very few seem to stay.

Comment: Ah well. It's a bit of a different environment to (say) cooking, where if you are interested in it you are likely to stay and discuss things. Being an environment for newbies, the Arduino SE tends to attract people who just want to get their homework done. Of course, this isn't everyone.

Comment: it happened again

Answer (score 3):

- 75% of users on this site turn up, ask one question, get their answer, and are never seen again.
- 22% of users on this site turn up, ask one question, don't bother waiting around for an answer, and are never seen again.
- 2% of users on this site are those that show an interest and either want to help others or have an inquiring mind that wants to learn more.
- The remaining 1% are us.

(Statistics source: the back of my sofa)

Of all the users on the site maybe 3% would find it useful. 1% of those would use it to whinge about the 97% that never come back, the others wouldn't even know it was there.

So what use is a general chat room? Most chat discussions are related to a specific question/answer and thus are between just a couple of people for a short time, and those chat rooms can be created at will as they are needed.

Comment: I agree, which is probably a problem in it's own. Pin 13 getting frozen is just one of the results. But it's not the only one, probably also why the beta takes so long or question quality is low on average (afaik)? I'm not sure if and how we can improve it, I think it's because Arduino is specifically aimed at hobbyists. Which also isn't something that could/would/should change?  The main point was that I thought it would be weird to just give up on a general chat because of it, but a general chat also needs a topic from time to time. (And in that case we could use a designated chatroom aswel)