# Pin 13 chat room is frozen

Tags: support, chat

[A moderator can unfreeze it?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/pin-13-frozen)

[image]

(*and the question wizard requires some more text*)

Comment: Ok, try it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left you a test message in the Pin 13 chat room.

> and the question wizard requires some more text

What is the "question wizard"?

Comment: it was just a dummy text because so short question is not allowed

Comment: still frozen. the field to enter a new message is missing. I added a screenshot to question